# USB driver for Samsung Galaxy S Duos 2

Tags: samsung, usb-drivers, samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2

I'm looking for a USB driver for my phone [Samsung GT-S7582 S Duos 2](http://www.samsung.com/levant/consumer/mobile-phones/mobile-phones/duos/GT-S7582ZKAMID). Can't find it in Samsung Official Site. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install  [kies](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP) in your PC. It will automatically install corresponding USB drivers.

**EDIT:**
[Samsung Kies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Kies) is a freeware software application used to communicate between Windows or Mac operating systems, and more recently manufactured Samsung mobile phone and tablet computer devices, usually using a USB cable connection (though wireless LAN Kies connectivity is now possible using some devices).

This software may be used for:

1. Data backup
2. Data transfer (between a Windows or Mac PC, and a Samsung mobile device), limited to certain media file formats.
3. Multimedia (audio, photos, video, etc.) management, but limited to certain file formats.
4. Purchase/acquisition of additional or special device features.
5. Device firmware and operating system (OS version) upgrades.

To work all these, USB driver should be installed. So When you install this software it will automatically detect your device and install USB drivers.

Comment: Can I know what is this software for?

Comment: After I installed Kies, I tried to run the following command line from Android SDK but it still doesn't show the device.

Comment: C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices

Comment: USB debugging is ON in developer options?

Comment: Do as http://stackoverflow.com/a/21817956/1000676 ,and if you are connected to internet choose windows update.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can find my device listed now. But I still cannot run very simple android application and I get the above screen shot with OK button disabled. I think there is still something missing, right?

Comment: Thank you very much. neglect the last comment. I had to accept debugging from this computer. I have no problems now.

Answer (score -1):

Install moborobo. Never fails. It will get you drivers automatically. Then download SRS root & it will root it in one single click.